# How can I hide columns in an Excel output from SSRS that are not generated by the report?

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I need to generate a cover page for an SSRS report, along the lines of this example in Excel:
[image: Cover page]

Note on this image the hidden columns after N and rows after 30. Is it possible to force SSRS to hide these columns & rows?

I can't find anything about hiding these when not generating the columns, and I've tried generating the columns with a simple column group. Using `=iif(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCELOPENXML" OrElse Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", True, False)` does not work on generated columns; it hide the data, not the column.

For reference, the test report looks like this:

[image: Test Report]

And the dataset is generated with this SQL:

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;
set nocount on;

select top 255
    n.Number
from dbo.Numbers as [n]
```

**EDIT**: For those who don't have a numbers table, you can use:

```
select top 256
    row_number() over (order by v.number) as [Number]
from master..spt_values as [v]
```

My numbers table starts at 0, hence 255 in that and 256 in the alternative.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I suspected as much. Toggled visibility almost gets there, but then the toggle leaves it looking poor.